# Is there a way to weight instances based upon the values of a feature?

Tags: orange

Is there a way to weight instances based upon the values of a feature? 
For instance for making a sample better resemble a population on certain parameters.

Comment: Are these weights static? Or it may change along with the training?

Answer (score 1):

Try reading up on Loss/ Cost functions. Samples that are closer to your model will be assigned a smaller cost while others a higher one.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function

Answer (score 1):

In [Orange documentation - Loading your Data](https://orange-visual-programming.readthedocs.io/loading-your-data/index.html#header-with-attribute-type-information), it says to prefix your column with `w#` to be marked as instance weights column.